# Setting DAY view in Kendo UI Scheduler from date picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I am using Kendo UI to show scheduler control.

I am also havving date picker

This is the DIV contains the calendar.

```
        <div id="calendar">

         </div>
```

I load calendar from script as follow

```
     <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {


              $("#calendar").kendoCalendar();
          });
   </script>
```

I have scheduler as follow

```
                 <td>
                @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<SchedulingSystemUI.Models.TaskViewModel>()
        .Name("scheduler")
        .Date(new DateTime(2014, 8, 16))
        .StartTime(new DateTime(2014, 8, 16, 7, 00, 00))
        .Height(600)
        .Views(views =>
        {
            views.DayView();
            views.WeekView(weekView => weekView.Selected(true));
            views.MonthView();
            views.AgendaView();
        })
        .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
        .DataSource(d => d
            .Model(m =>
            {
                m.Id(f => f.TaskID);
                m.Field(f => f.OwnerID).DefaultValue(1);
                //Set the recurrence ID field from the model:
                m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);
            })
                    .Read("Tasks_Read", "Dashboard")
                                .Create("Tasks_Create", "Dashboard")
                                    .Destroy("Tasks_Destroy", "Dashboard")
                                    .Update("Tasks_Update", "Dashboard")
        )
                )


            </td>
```

Now on clicking date picker, i want to change the Scheduler VIEW to DAY.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the scheduler's [view method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#methods-view) to change the view to the day view.

```
var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.view("month");
```

The tricky part is when to trigger this change.  It could be when the datepicker gets the focus.  The challenge here is the API has no focus event, but you'd have to capture the focus of one of the underlying elements, if supported.  I know it hides the actual input element for some of the widgets, so i'm not sure how the focus event would work.

Also, you could trigger it to fire on opening of the calendar, which is supported.

Comment: it will trigger when user clicks the date on jQuery calendar control

Comment: jQuery or kendo?  Your tags say kendo.  And clicking on the control fires the `open` event, which you can attach to.